# Any real-world implications for general catch clause emitting System.Object as type filter?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

I recall hearing once that throwing an object of some type other than `System.Exception` (or those extending it) was technically legal CIL, though C# has no feature to support it. So I was interested to see that the following C# code:

```
try {
    throw new Exception();
} catch(Exception x) {
    try {
        throw;
    } catch {
        Console.Write("yes");
    }
}
```

compiles to the following CIL:

```
  .try
  {
    IL_0000:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.Exception::.ctor()
    IL_0005:  throw
  }  // end .try
  catch [mscorlib]System.Exception 
  {
    IL_0006:  pop
    .try
    {
      IL_0007:  rethrow
    }  // end .try
    catch [mscorlib]System.Object 
    {
      IL_0009:  pop
      IL_000a:  ldstr      "yes"
      IL_000f:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::Write(string)
      IL_0014:  leave.s    IL_0016
    }  // end handler
    IL_0016:  leave.s    IL_0018
  }  // end handler
```

where we see that the nested general catch clause compiles to:

```
catch [mscorlib]System.Object
```

in C#, are there any real-world implications for general catch clause emitting `System.Object` as type filter instead of `System.Exception`?

Comment: ..I would just assume that the implications are one in the same.. its still a "dirty" catch-all.

Comment: Up 'till now, I've always thought that the general `catch` was equivalent to `catch(Exception x)` just without the variable binding... now I see that they are certainly not. So I guess I'm wondering if there are any real-world scenarios where this need to be considered (i.e. do any .NET apps throw non-`Exception` objects that someone might want to handle?).

Comment: Its quite a huge question that only very specific people could answer. Ive never seen non-`Exception` derived objects thrown whilst browsing the framework libraries .. but they are so vast it would be impossible to confirm that for sure. Although, given most of it is written in C# you may be able to rule that out!

Comment: Note that since .Net 2.0, thrown non-`Exception` objects are wrapped in `RuntimeWrappedException` by default. Although you can override this by using [`RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimecompatibilityattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *is* a difference pre .NET-2.0. I read about it in the .NET 1.1 days.

[It is explained here (I won't copy it)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3391815/122718). Note that the first answer is wrong and the second is right.

As to whether it is practical or not: No. I guess it was important for obscure interop scenarios.